# Is there a recognised record for Minesweeper on a Cell phone?

Tags: competitive-gaming, minesweeper

Is there a current record for an expert game played on a touch screen cell phone and/or tablet?

I put up a 98 second expert game on my phone and I'm curious how good that is compared to the 'best'

Comment: Seems like most of the world records are for PCs.  I don't know that anyone is tracking for tablet/phone devices - http://www.minesweeper.info/worldrecords/

Comment: I'm VTC but for a different reason. There is (afaik) no canonical competitive Minesweeper implementation for mobile--unlike desktop, which uses Minesweeper X--so even if such a stat was tracked, it would hardly be meaningful.

Comment: @Schism - 'It doesn't exist' is actually a [valid answer](http://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8484/28182) - (while this meta is specific to Plot/Lore, the same reasoning applies here): *"If there is no answer at the moment, we can either leave it open to be potentially answered later or we can offer that as an answer and update if more information is later revealed."*

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, there doesn't appear to be any competitive listing of Minesweeper times as played on a mobile device. While many versions & clones of Minesweeper exist for many platforms, the competitive players appear to stick to desktop-PC versions.

In terms of world rankings, [Authoritative Minesweeper](http://www.minesweeper.info/) is the most recognised source (in Western culture at least).

> The ranking started in April 2000 and in October 2012 was accepted by Guinness World Records - [Minesweeper Wiki: World Ranking History](http://www.minesweeper.info/wiki/World_Ranking_History)

You can check out some of the best times posted [here](http://www.minesweeper.info/worldrecords/).

---

So which versions of the game are used competitively? According to the [Minesweeper Wiki](http://www.minesweeper.info/wiki/Tournaments), competitive Minesweeper is usually played on competitively-sanctioned clones of the original Minesweeper:

> #### Programs
>
> Most tournaments used official clones of minesweeper. Budapest 08 used Windows Vista because it was sponsored by Microsoft. Vienna 06/07/08, Budapest 07, Munich 10, UK 11 and Zurich 11 used Viennasweeper, which was not an official world ranking clone until 2008 but was given permission by the IMC to be used. Budapest 05/06 and Vienna 05 used Clone 0.96. Shanghai 07 used Clone 0.97, while all other tournaments used Clone 2007.

Whilst one of the tournaments listed above used the version of Minesweeper that came with Windows Vista, do note that Microsoft versions [aren't allowed anymore](http://www.minesweeper.info/ranking/rules.html):

> Microsoft minesweeper is no longer allowed on the rankings except in special cases. There are many reasons. First, it uses a small number of boards that repeat. Players began using board cycles to play the same board multiple times. This is an example of Unfair Prior Knowledge. UPK is also a problem of Vista minesweeper, because you are allowed to play a game many times until you win.